# Can't connect to the OpenVPN Server

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to connect to the openvpn server i installed on centos7 (following this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7), the handshack seems to be happening, however the connection keeps resetting. Below are the log:

**Client Side**

```
Wed Jun 28 23:42:48 2017 OpenVPN 2.3.11 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] 
[PKCS11] [IPv6] built on May 10 2016
Wed Jun 28 23:42:48 2017 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater) 64bit
Wed Jun 28 23:42:48 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.09
Wed Jun 28 23:42:48 2017 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Wed Jun 28 23:42:48 2017 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Wed Jun 28 23:42:48 2017 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Wed Jun 28 23:42:48 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Wed Jun 28 23:42:48 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Wed Jun 28 23:42:49 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Wed Jun 28 23:42:49 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Wed Jun 28 23:42:49 2017 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Wed Jun 28 23:42:49 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Wed Jun 28 23:42:49 2017 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]41.124.127.66:1194 [nonblock]
Wed Jun 28 23:42:49 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498686169,TCP_CONNECT,,,
Wed Jun 28 23:42:50 2017 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]41.124.127.66:1194
Wed Jun 28 23:42:50 2017 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Wed Jun 28 23:42:50 2017 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]41.124.127.66:1194
Wed Jun 28 23:42:50 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498686170,WAIT,,,
Wed Jun 28 23:42:50 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498686170,AUTH,,,
Wed Jun 28 23:42:50 2017 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]41.124.127.66:1194, sid=16544047 8d1189bc
Wed Jun 28 23:42:52 2017 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
Wed Jun 28 23:42:52 2017 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Wed Jun 28 23:42:52 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498686172,RECONNECTING,connection-reset,,
Wed Jun 28 23:42:52 2017 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
Wed Jun 28 23:42:57 2017 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Wed Jun 28 23:42:57 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Wed Jun 28 23:42:57 2017 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]41.124.127.66:1194 [nonblock]
Wed Jun 28 23:42:57 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498686177,TCP_CONNECT,,,
Wed Jun 28 23:42:58 2017 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]41.124.127.66:1194
Wed Jun 28 23:42:58 2017 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Wed Jun 28 23:42:58 2017 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]41.124.127.66:1194
Wed Jun 28 23:42:58 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498686178,WAIT,,,
Wed Jun 28 23:42:58 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498686178,AUTH,,,
Wed Jun 28 23:42:58 2017 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]41.124.127.66:1194, sid=97dc8edb 5fa1846c
Wed Jun 28 23:42:58 2017 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
Wed Jun 28 23:42:58 2017 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Wed Jun 28 23:42:58 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498686178,RECONNECTING,connection-reset,,
Wed Jun 28 23:42:58 2017 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

**Server Side**

```
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261389 Current Parameter Settings:
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261470   config = 'server.conf'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261483   mode = 1
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261491   persist_config = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261498   persist_mode = 1
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261504   show_ciphers = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261510   show_digests = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261516   show_engines = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261522   genkey = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261528   key_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261535   show_tls_ciphers = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261542 Connection profiles [default]:
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261549   proto = tcp-server
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261555   local = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261562   local_port = 1194
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261568   remote = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261574   remote_port = 1194
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261580   remote_float = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261586   bind_defined = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261592   bind_local = ENABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261598   connect_retry_seconds = 5
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261604   connect_timeout = 10
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261610   connect_retry_max = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261616   socks_proxy_server = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261623   socks_proxy_port = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261628   socks_proxy_retry = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261635   tun_mtu = 1500
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261641   tun_mtu_defined = ENABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261647   link_mtu = 1500
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261653   link_mtu_defined = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261659   tun_mtu_extra = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261665   tun_mtu_extra_defined = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261671   mtu_discover_type = -1
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261677   fragment = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261683   mssfix = 1450
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261689   explicit_exit_notification = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261695 Connection profiles END
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261701   remote_random = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261707   ipchange = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261718   dev = 'tun'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261727   dev_type = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261733   dev_node = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261739   lladdr = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261746   topology = 1
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261752   tun_ipv6 = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261759   ifconfig_local = '10.8.0.1'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261765   ifconfig_remote_netmask = '10.8.0.2'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261771   ifconfig_noexec = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261777   ifconfig_nowarn = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261783   ifconfig_ipv6_local = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261789   ifconfig_ipv6_netbits = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261796   ifconfig_ipv6_remote = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261802   shaper = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261808   mtu_test = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261814   mlock = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261821   keepalive_ping = 10
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261828   keepalive_timeout = 120
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261835   inactivity_timeout = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261841   ping_send_timeout = 10
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261847   ping_rec_timeout = 240
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261853   ping_rec_timeout_action = 2
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261859   ping_timer_remote = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261865   remap_sigusr1 = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261871   persist_tun = ENABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261877   persist_local_ip = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261883   persist_remote_ip = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261889   persist_key = ENABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261895   passtos = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261901   resolve_retry_seconds = 1000000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261915   username = 'nobody'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261922   groupname = 'nobody'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261928   chroot_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261934   cd_dir = '/etc/openvpn/'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261940   writepid = '/var/run/openvpn/server.pid'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261946   up_script = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261952   down_script = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261958   down_pre = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261965   up_restart = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261970   up_delay = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261976   daemon = ENABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261982   inetd = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261988   log = ENABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=261995   suppress_timestamps = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262001   nice = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262038   verbosity = 6
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262047   mute = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262053   gremlin = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262060   status_file = 'openvpn-status.log'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262066   status_file_version = 1
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262072   status_file_update_freq = 60
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262078   occ = ENABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262084   rcvbuf = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262090   sndbuf = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262096   mark = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262102   sockflags = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262108   fast_io = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262114   lzo = 7
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262120   route_script = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262126   route_default_gateway = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262132   route_default_metric = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262139   route_noexec = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262145   route_delay = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262151   route_delay_window = 30
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262157   route_delay_defined = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262163   route_nopull = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262170   route_gateway_via_dhcp = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262176   max_routes = 100
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262182   allow_pull_fqdn = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262189   route 10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0/nil/nil
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262196   management_addr = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262202   management_port = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262221   management_user_pass = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262229   management_log_history_cache = 250
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262235   management_echo_buffer_size = 100
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262242   management_write_peer_info_file = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262248   management_client_user = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262254   management_client_group = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262261   management_flags = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262267   shared_secret_file = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262273   key_direction = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262280   ciphername_defined = ENABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262286   ciphername = 'BF-CBC'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262293   authname_defined = ENABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262299   authname = 'SHA1'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262305   prng_hash = 'SHA1'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262312   prng_nonce_secret_len = 16
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262318   keysize = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262324   engine = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262330   replay = ENABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262336   mute_replay_warnings = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262342   replay_window = 64
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262348   replay_time = 15
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262354   packet_id_file = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262360   use_iv = ENABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262366   test_crypto = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262372   tls_server = ENABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262378   tls_client = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262384   key_method = 2
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262396   ca_file = 'ca.crt'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262402   ca_path = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262408   dh_file = 'dh2048.pem'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262414   cert_file = 'server.crt'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262421   extra_certs_file = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262427   priv_key_file = 'server.key'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262434   pkcs12_file = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262440   cipher_list = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262446   tls_verify = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262452   tls_export_cert = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262459   verify_x509_type = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262467   verify_x509_name = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262474   crl_file = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262480   ns_cert_type = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262486   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262492   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262498   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262504   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262510   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262516   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262522   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262528   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262534   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262540   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262545   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262551   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262557   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262563   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262569   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262575   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262581   remote_cert_eku = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262587   ssl_flags = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262593   tls_timeout = 2
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262599   renegotiate_bytes = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262605   renegotiate_packets = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262611   renegotiate_seconds = 3600
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262617   handshake_window = 60
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262624   transition_window = 3600
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262630   single_session = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262636   push_peer_info = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262643   tls_exit = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262649   tls_auth_file = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262656   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262662   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262668   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262674   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262680   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262686   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262692   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262698   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262704   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262710   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262717   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262724   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262732   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262739   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262746   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262752   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262759   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262766   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262772   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262779   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262791   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262797   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262803   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262809   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262816   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262823   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262830   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262838   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262846   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262853   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262860   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262868   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262875   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262882   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262890   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262897   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262904   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262911   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262918   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262925   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262932   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262940   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262947   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262954   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262962   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262970   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262977   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262985   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=262993   pkcs11_pin_cache_period = -1
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263000   pkcs11_id = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263007   pkcs11_id_management = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263017   server_network = 10.8.0.0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263026   server_netmask = 255.255.255.0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263037   server_network_ipv6 = ::
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263044   server_netbits_ipv6 = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263052   server_bridge_ip = 0.0.0.0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263060   server_bridge_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263073   server_bridge_pool_start = 0.0.0.0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263082   server_bridge_pool_end = 0.0.0.0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263089   push_entry = 'redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263096   push_entry = 'dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263103   push_entry = 'dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263111   push_entry = 'route 10.8.0.1'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263118   push_entry = 'topology net30'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263125   push_entry = 'ping 10'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263133   push_entry = 'ping-restart 120'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263140   ifconfig_pool_defined = ENABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263148   ifconfig_pool_start = 10.8.0.4
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263156   ifconfig_pool_end = 10.8.0.251
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263164   ifconfig_pool_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263171   ifconfig_pool_persist_filename = 'ipp.txt'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263179   ifconfig_pool_persist_refresh_freq = 600
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263186   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_defined = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263194   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_base = ::
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263201   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_netbits = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263218   n_bcast_buf = 256
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263227   tcp_queue_limit = 64
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263234   real_hash_size = 256
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263241   virtual_hash_size = 256
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263249   client_connect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263255   learn_address_script = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263269   client_disconnect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263276   client_config_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263283   ccd_exclusive = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263290   tmp_dir = '/tmp'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263297   push_ifconfig_defined = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263306   push_ifconfig_local = 0.0.0.0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263315   push_ifconfig_remote_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263322   push_ifconfig_ipv6_defined = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263329   push_ifconfig_ipv6_local = ::/0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263336   push_ifconfig_ipv6_remote = ::
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263342   enable_c2c = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263349   duplicate_cn = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263355   cf_max = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263362   cf_per = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263368   max_clients = 1024
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263375   max_routes_per_client = 256
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263382   auth_user_pass_verify_script = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263388   auth_user_pass_verify_script_via_file = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263394   port_share_host = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263401   port_share_port = 0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263407   client = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263413   pull = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263419   auth_user_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263427 OpenVPN 2.3.11 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on May 10 2016
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=263443 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013, LZO 2.06
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=275926 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=276626 TLS-Auth MTU parms [ L:1544 D:1210 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=276665 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=276851 ROUTE_GATEWAY 41.124.254.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=eth0 HWADDR=f2:3c:91:79:07:a1
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=277532 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=277560 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=277575 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=277601 /usr/sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=282681 /usr/sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=288983 /usr/sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=290287 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1544 D:1450 EF:44 EB:143 ET:0 EL:3 AF:3/1 ]
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=290677 GID set to nobody
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=290696 UID set to nobody
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=290709 Listening for incoming TCP connection on [undef]
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=290721 TCPv4_SERVER link local (bound): [undef]
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=290727 TCPv4_SERVER link remote: [undef]
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=290737 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=290769 IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.4 size=62, ipv6=0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=290779 ifconfig_pool_read(), in='client,10.8.0.4', TODO: IPv6
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=290788 succeeded -> ifconfig_pool_set()
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=290794 IFCONFIG POOL LIST
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=290800 client,10.8.0.4
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=290818 MULTI: TCP INIT maxclients=1024 maxevents=1028
Wed Jun 28 21:34:02 2017 us=290838 Initialization Sequence Completed
Wed Jun 28 21:34:12 2017 us=294771 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Wed Jun 28 21:34:12 2017 us=294934 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Wed Jun 28 21:34:12 2017 us=295009 LZO compression initialized
Wed Jun 28 21:34:12 2017 us=295144 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1544 D:1210 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Wed Jun 28 21:34:12 2017 us=295166 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1544 D:1450 EF:44 EB:143 ET:0 EL:3 AF:3/1 ]
Wed Jun 28 21:34:12 2017 us=295194 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1544,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_SERVER,comp-lzo,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:12 2017 us=295225 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1544,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,comp-lzo,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:12 2017 us=295241 Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'c0103fa8'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:12 2017 us=295250 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '69109d17'
Wed Jun 28 21:34:12 2017 us=295282 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]45.247.102.142:52355
Wed Jun 28 21:34:12 2017 us=295291 TCPv4_SERVER link local: [undef]
Wed Jun 28 21:34:12 2017 us=295296 TCPv4_SERVER link remote: [AF_INET]45.247.102.142:52355
Wed Jun 28 21:34:13 2017 us=467508 45.247.102.142:52355 TCPv4_SERVER READ [14] from [AF_INET]45.247.102.142:52355: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:13 2017 us=467577 45.247.102.142:52355 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]45.247.102.142:52355, sid=5758c05e 539a249f
Wed Jun 28 21:34:13 2017 us=467615 45.247.102.142:52355 TCPv4_SERVER WRITE [26] to [AF_INET]45.247.102.142:52355: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ 0 ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Wed Jun 28 21:34:13 2017 us=967139 45.247.102.142:52355 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
Wed Jun 28 21:34:13 2017 us=967232 45.247.102.142:52355 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
Wed Jun 28 21:34:13 2017 us=967384 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
```

And it ends open having this restart loop. I can't figure out from the logs what im doing wrong.

Comment: What do the logs say on the other side of the connection?

Comment: @Zoredache added the server log as well

Comment: Do you use an OpenVPN static key?

Comment: @Alexander yes i do, i switched from tcp to udp and that solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply changed the server protocol from tcp to udp and that solved the problem. Not sure why though as always